Is there a simple way to do number operations in a limited number space in python?
I want to know if there is a simple method to do number equations in a limited number space like 0 and 40 or 0 and 1000? Even better if there is a way for numbers to go back.
For example, have a number space between 0 and 8. Then do operation 4 + 7 which would be equal to 11 (over 8) and then this number will go back to 5, because 4 + 4 would be 8 and because there is still a residue of 3 (7 - 4 = 3) which then equal to 8 - 3 which is 5. And vice versa with substraction where 3 - 4 would be equal to 1 in a 0 to 8 number space.
I tried to do bunch of ifs, but stopped, because it made code a little bit complicated.

I would want for numbers to go back. Like they bumping into wall and then go back. So that in 3 - 3 = 0. And a residue of one would bounce back to 1 and not be 8 - 1 which would be equal to 7.

Only addition and subtraction or also other operations?

Yes, only addition and subtraction. I used %, but 9%8=1, where I would want for it to be 8 or 7 depending on the limits.

Are you asking about modular arithmetic? 4 + 7 ≡ 3 (mod 8), since 4 + 7 == 11 and 11 % 8 == 3. It's not built into Python, so you have to use % explicitly to reduce values.

@nocomment I'd really like to hear a clearer explanation from the OP.

For example I would like to have hard number limits like 0 and 8(which would be like "walls") And then do numbers operations beween these walls, where 3 - 4 would be 1, because it would be 3 - 3 - 1 = -1, but you cannot go out of "walls" and you bounce back so -1 would go back and be 1.

@chepner Oh, you mean are they asking how to compute the 3 that they then subtract?

Why is your lower limit 0 in all those examples? Is it always 0?

Actually, now when I think about it being able to choose between -8 to 8 or 0 to 8 limits would be nice.

It's periodic with period twice the size of your space. For example with space from 0 to 8, adding 16 or 32 or 48 etc doesn't have an effect. So use modulo twice the size. Then you have at most one bump off a wall, which I handled with a min. To support nonzero lower ends, surround the actual calculation by shifting the lower end to zero and back (i.e., subtract lo from the given a and add it back at the end).
def add(a, b, lo, hi):
    p = 2 * (hi-lo)
    s = (a-lo + b) % p
    return min(s, p-s) + lo

def sub(a, b, lo, hi):
    return add(a, -b, lo, hi)

print(add(4, 7, 0, 8))
print(sub(3, 4, 0, 8))
print(*(add(5, i, 3, 6) for i in range(15)))

Output (Attempt This Online!):
5
1
5 6 5 4 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 4 5 6 5

